# SharePoint 2013 deployment

Tags: 2013, deployment

I recently installed SharePoint 2013 on a VM with windows server 2008 and swl 2012. But I need some direction to start configuring the SharePoint. I found microsoft tech notes too complicated. Can anyone who experienced this help me please.

Answer (score 3):

That's a pretty wide-open question. Configure for what? SharePoint provides a lot of functionality, which does require some complex, and sometimes frustrating setup.

I'm not sure what you mean by 'Microsoft Tech Notes'.. Do you mean TechNet? While it may seem complicated, there is truly a wealth of information in there which you'll need to understand if you want to have a working, solid SharePoint environment.

My best advice is to start here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/fp123606. These videos and presentations will give you a very broad overview on what to expect with SharePoint 2013. I wish I could say that a deployment is as easy as 'Next--> Next--> Finish', but as with any enterprise type application, it's not.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wanted to start by configuring basic features, but I didn't know how to start with them.

Comment: I found a really good VM guide on Critical Path Training's site. You'll have to register for a free account, but it's a guide I've been going on for a couple of years now.

Comment: That website looks amazing. But they do not have any free courses.

Comment: It's not a course, it's actually [something you can find in the 'Members' area](http://www.criticalpathtraining.com/Members/Pages/default.aspx) once you register. They just released V1.0 yesterday, and I built up my VM environment last night using it.

Comment: That was a great guide and it helped me to check if I was doing fine. Many thanks for that.

Comment: can i have your email address to exchange ideas if you are doing the same thing?